# type-erased C++ output iterator

Tags: c++, boost, stl, type-erasure

How to erase type from output iterators as `std::insert_iterator` and `std::back_insert_iterator`? Is it possible to use boost `any_iterator` to do so?

```c
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp>
#include <vector>

typedef boost::range_detail::any_iterator<
    int, boost::incrementable_traversal_tag, int &, std::ptrdiff_t > It;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    It outIt( v.begin() ); // compiles
    It inserter( std::back_inserter(v) ); // does not compile
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "erase type"?

Comment: @EitanT: You should look up "C++ type erasure", but for a short definition "the process of turning a wide variety of types with a common interface into one type with that same interface". Boost::Any would be the canonical example.

Comment: @JesseGood Aaa I know what that is, I never knew it is called "type erasure". Doh!

Comment: @EitanT: Here is a nice article about [type erasure](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html) and here is the [pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Erasure).

Comment: I can't quite get any sort of code that involves `boost::any_range` to compile using either GCC 4.6 or 4.7. Not only has the header `<boost/range/any_range.hpp>` its own issues (e.g. it doesn't work standalone, you need to include `<boost/range/concepts.hpp>` before it), but somehow with 4.7 there's a problem when `std::iterator_traits` is instantiated for the `iterator` type of an `any_range` instantiation. If I sidestep *that* then there's still a problem in the implementation of `any_range` which may or may not be related with two-phase lookups. Sorry, can't find anything further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`any_iterator` is not designed for use with *output iterators*, which is what `back_insert_iterator` is (or, for that matter, *input iterators*).

`back_insert_iterator` is defined to inherit from `iterator<output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>` i.e. its `value_type`, `reference_type`, `distance_type` and `pointer_type` are all `void`, but `any_iterator` expects to be able to indirect through its backing iterator to a non-void value.  Perhaps it would be better named `any_value_iterator`; but then it is a `detail` class template.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any alternatives in Boost?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; the problem is that `boost::iterator_facade` expects to be able to define `operator[]` and `operator->` in-class.
It shouldn't be too difficult to define yourself using `boost::function` to wrap the `operator=` (which is the only part of an output iterator that actually matters).

Answer (score 5):

So I implemented my own one using Boost.

```c
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

template < class T >
class AnyInserter : public boost::function_output_iterator< boost::function< void ( const T & value ) > >
{
private:
    typedef typename boost::function_output_iterator< boost::function< void ( const T & value ) > > BaseType;
    template < class OutIt > struct Insert
    {
        Insert( OutIt it ) : m_it(it) {}
        void operator () ( const T & value ) { m_it++ = value; }
        OutIt m_it;
    };
public:
    template < class OutIt >
        explicit AnyInserter( const OutIt & it ) : BaseType( Insert< OutIt >(it) ) {}
};

template < class OutIt >
    inline AnyInserter< typename OutIt::container_type::value_type >
    makeAnyInserter( const OutIt & it ) 
    {
        return AnyInserter< typename OutIt::container_type::value_type >(it);
    }
```

Comment: That looks fine.  One point is that instead of `typename OutIt::container_type::value_type` you might want to use `typename std::iterator_traits<OutIt>::value_type` so that you can use your template with e.g. raw pointers.